# Display results on the browser instantly without waiting for PHP code to execute completely

Tags: php

I wrote a php code that connects to my sqlite3 database (using PDO) and retrieve some data. The output result is big, thus it takes 5 or 6 minutes for my php code to finish execution, and see the results.

Is it possible to display some results on the browser while the php code is running. I don't want to wait for the whole php script to be executed completely. I am new to web-programming and I am using XAMPP.

Comment: Have you considered optimizing your query/queries? 5-6 minutes is a long time, you might be able to cut that down a lot. Web sockets might help, but not all browsers support them. Long polling is another async method to wait for a response. What you probably would have to do is offload the work to another process on your server (`cron`, for instance), and then refresh until the end of the script signals to the browser through a polling script that it's finished, and then send the results to the client.

Comment: @njk: I tested the AJAX code in this page: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first. It worked. In that code, when the button is pressed, loadXMLDoc() is executed. but the question is: can I call the loadXMLDoc() function from my php code?

Comment: Your query is seriously flawed if it takes minutes. The measuring stick of queries on web servers is in milliseconds, or maybe a second or two, at most, if the server is handling a lot of traffic. You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: The database contains millions of records. The output result of query is big (around 500,000 records) and I write each of them into a file for further processing. But I will try your suggestions as well. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should chunk it and load it progressively, for instance with a paging scheme. Why on God's green earth would you need to all at once drop 100k records to the client browser? Another option, as well, is [Gearman](http://gearman.org/gearman_php_extension).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: because the http server is mostly accessible by 2 persons. We need all of the 500k data from the database.

Comment: On another note, I was talking to my general practitioner the other day, who had mentioned a couple years back he had originally been working on a PhD in data analytics. The other day, it was slow so we got to talking, and I asked him about what he had done. In the early 90s he had worked for what became Sabre Holdings doing C-Lisp development. What was the problem he solved? Reducing scheduling queries for inter'l airline flight searches. He worked for a year and a half to drop a regular 30 minute wait to five minutes that's still in use. Moral? It's hard to solve big data problems. He quit.

Comment: 500k? In the *browser*? What? You could probably ship the whole sqlite file to the browser and run it from it there quicker. If you're taking a literal approach to your data consumption, you're doing it wrong. If you're not familiar, look up OLAP, Redis.io and MapReduce if you're working with data three dimensionally. And sqlite is probably not a great product at this scale, MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, postgresql, or possibly something like Drizzle or Cassandra might be more appropriate, knowing no details of your use case.